# Issue with elements of dimensional lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I'm new in python and I found a problem. When I use this code and I got desire output.

```
    list1=[[1,3,5,7],
    [18,9,23,30]
    
    
    ]
    list2 = [1,3,7]
    print(list1[0].index(1))
output = 0
```

But when I use this code I got wrong output despite the fact that 1 is in this list.

```
list1=[[1,3,5,7],
[18,9,23,30]


]
list2 = [1,3,7]
print(list1[0].index(1))
for element in list2:
    if element in list1:
        print(list1[0].index(element))
    else:
        print("Element not in list1")
```

output = 0
Element not in list1
Element not in list1
Element not in list1

Why this works like that? The second issue is that I used     print(list1[0].index(1)) to get the second index, because I knew that this letter will be in row =0. Is it a more universal way to get only the second or only the first index no matter if we know the number of column or row?

Comment: `for element in list2:` loops over integers. `if element in list1:` will be false because `list1` is a list of lists - not a list of integers.

Comment: So how to change the second function if it can work? Because if I loop over the list1 I will get the 1 list, so I won't have double index

Answer (score 0):

`element` is an integer and `list1` is a list of lists so `element` will not be in `list1` directly (it might be in one of the sub-lists of `list1`). You can search each sub-list in `list1` with a nested loop:

```
for element in list2:
    for index,sub_list in enumerate(list1):
        if element in sub_list:
            print(f"{element} found at list1[{index}][{sub_list.index(element)}]")
            break
    else:
        print(f"{element} not in list1")
```